# Что лучше, 15мб зависимостей или свой велосипед?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

При разработке публичного npm пакета часто возникает вопрос, использовать ли существующее решение, которое тянет с собой чуть-ли не половину всех популярных пакетов с npm, или написать свой велосипед.

Чтобы сузить область, уточню детали. Свой велосипед - это примерно 1000-1500 строк кода без зависимостей, естественно есть вероятность наделать много багов (но это как повезет). Время на разработку и отладку - день-два. Альтернатива - пакет который отлично решает эту задачу но тащит с собой ~150 вложенных зависимостей на ~15мб.

Как считаете, что предпочтительнее? И по каким критериям прежде всего решаете, какой сделать выбор в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

В разработке ПО есть принцип KISS (keep it simple, stupid — «делай это проще, дурачок»). Вполне логичный, в *nix системах очень распространенный. На мой взгляд в общем случае надо работать в соответствии с ним...

НО. Нужно трезво оценивать цели и задачи своего решения, и стороннего решения.
Если оно создано, поддерживается и развивается известным надежным разработчиком, если нужный вам функционал не является в этом решении "побочным". То почему нет?
Так же стоит подумать. Набор который тянется: на сколько велик шанс, что он будет крайне полезным в проекте, который использует ваше решение; не будет ли большая вероятность конфликтов с аналогичными решениями (или разница в версиях).
Так же важно понять значимость этого функционала в вашем проекте. Возможно вы один раз напишете эти 1500 строк и хватит на долгие годы, это одно. (тогда этот вариант вполне годен) Другое, если гарантированно эти 1500 строк потребуют и поддержки и развития и, как следствие, сократят доступное время на разработку основного функционала

Как пользователь история к месту: попросили меня как-то LAMP на чистую винду поставить. Если не ошибаюсь инсталлятор MySQL был написан на .Net. В итоге ради установки ПО которому не нужен NET потребовалось выкачивать сотню мегабайт... Подумайте если велик шанс, что среди пользователей вашего решения большей части вряд ли понадобятся все эти зависимости - значит лучше свой велосипед...

Answer (score 23):

В мире npm как то принято тянуть побольше зависимостей. И тут выход такой:

- если это Ваш личный проект, тогда можно делать как нравится. В личных проектах велосипеды - самая правильная вещь (если цель проекта освоить новые технологии).
- если это проект "на попробовать", "взлетит/не взлетит" (ака стартап) - тогда побольше зависимостей, поменьше своего кода. Нам же идею проверять, инвесторов потенциальных радовать, а не код вылизывать. Потом, возможно, можно будет и переписать.
- если это проект рабочий (то есть, делается на работе), тогда лучше спросить у менеджера/тимлида/и тому подобное. Если сам тимлид/менеджер, тогда пункты выше. Но тут может оказаться, что юротдел может сказать, что некоторые пакеты имеют "неправильные лицензии" или "сомнительное происхождение" и их придется делать самому.

Но тут есть ещё одна штука. Нужно смотреть, а что за зависимости. Мало чего там. Может они конфиденциальную информацию собирают и в закрома засылают. И прецеденты уже были.

Мне также нравится следующая система. Собираем проект с готовых пакетов, смотрим, что бы лицензии у них были "хорошие, с возможностью модификации". А потом, когда проект "похоже работает", начинаем вычищать, переписывая критические участки. К примеру, можно использовать одну мелкую функцию с огромного пакета. Вполне возможно, что есть смысл ее извлечь в отдельный свой пакет. Хотя сейчас набегут хипстеры-оптимизаторы и скажут: "а вдруг завтра понадобиться ещё одна функция? и что извлекать снова? диски сейчас большие, памяти много, процессор пользователь докупит". Но таких нужно игнорировать и пользоваться здравым смыслом.

Comment: Извиняюсь за оффтоп, как то сразу в голове всплыла история с хабра когда 85% веса какого то фреймворка занимал JSON на 17к строк со словами на букву "G" и наличие в каждой из установок babel'я фото Гая Фиери...

Comment: @justyx так то информация из данной статьи просто шутка.